# How do you animate different Core Animation layers simultaneously?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I'm currently trying to implement an animation using Core Animation on iOS. Right now I can apply multiple animations to a single layer using CAAnimationGroup, but if I want to repeat that across various different layers --- simultaneously --- things get hazy.

Currently it looks like CAAnimationGroup is a singleton class (or at least, I only seem to get one instance, and I allocate using [CAAnimationGroup animation].

Any ideas?

```
NSMutableDictionary* elementInstanceData = [self.elementInstanceValues objectForKey:elementInstance];
                NSArray* animationValues = [elementInstanceData objectForKey:@"animationValues"];
                NSArray* keyTimeValues = [elementInstanceData objectForKey:@"keyTimeValues"];
                NSNumber* elementDurationTime = elementInstanceData[@"duration"];
                if(animationValues != nil)
                {
                    NSMutableArray* transValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    NSMutableArray* scaleValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    NSMutableArray* rotateValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                    for(NSDictionary* transforms in animationValues)
                    {
                        NSValue* trans = transforms[@"translate"];
                        [transValues addObject:trans];

                        NSValue* scale = transforms[@"scale"];
                        [scaleValues addObject:scale];

                        NSValue* rotate = transforms[@"rotate"];
                        [rotateValues addObject:rotate];
                    }

                    NSMutableArray* ratioTimeValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                    for(NSNumber* time in keyTimeValues)
                    {
                        float percentage = ([time floatValue] / [elementDurationTime floatValue]);
                        [ratioTimeValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:percentage ]];
                    }

                    NSCAssert( [ratioTimeValues count] == [transValues count], @"Keytime/value mismatch (times:%d, values: %d)", [ratioTimeValues count], [transValues count]) ;

                    CAKeyframeAnimation* transAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
                    [transAnim setValues:transValues];
                    [transAnim setKeyTimes:ratioTimeValues];
                    transAnim.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + startTime;
                    transAnim.duration = durationTime;
                    [allAnimations addObject:transAnim];

                    CAKeyframeAnimation* scaleAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
                    [scaleAnim setValues:scaleValues];
                    [scaleAnim setKeyTimes:ratioTimeValues];
                    scaleAnim.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + startTime;
                    scaleAnim.duration = durationTime;
                    [allAnimations addObject:scaleAnim];

                    CAKeyframeAnimation* rotAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
                    [rotAnim setValues:rotateValues];
                    [rotAnim setKeyTimes:ratioTimeValues];
                    rotAnim.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + startTime;
                    rotAnim.duration = durationTime;
                    [allAnimations addObject:rotAnim];
                }

                CAAnimationGroup* elementInstanceAnimationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
                elementInstanceAnimationGroup.animations = allAnimations;
                elementInstanceAnimationGroup.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
                elementInstanceAnimationGroup.duration = [elementDurationTime floatValue];
                elementInstanceAnimationGroup.delegate = self;

                [elementInstanceData setObject:elementInstanceAnimationGroup forKey:@"animationGroup"];
                UIView* targetView = [elementInstanceData objectForKey:@"target"];
                [targetView.layer addAnimation:elementInstanceAnimationGroup forKey:nil];
```

Comment: You can create an animation group and add it to multiple layers no problem. Do you have a sample of code that you think should be working?

Comment: How does adding the same CAAnimationGroup to multiple layers work if the animations property defines a collection of animations specific to a certain layer? I would want different animations/keyTime values for each layer. So I don't get how a single CAAnimationGroup would now which animations need to be applied to which layers.

Comment: Ok, if you need different animations for different layers, do that. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> I can apply multiple animations to a single layer using CAAnimationGroup, but if I want to repeat that across various different layers --- simultaneously --- things get hazy.

A single animation group can animate properties of different named sublayers.

For example, suppose I have a layer with two sublayers. The `name` of the first sublayer is `"manny"` and the `name` of the second sublayer is `"moe"`. And let's say I want to animate the `position` of the two sublayers individually.

Then I use a `keyPath` of `"sublayers.manny.position"` for one animation, and a `keyPath` of `"sublayers.moe.position"`, group them, and attach the group to the superlayer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an animation or animation group and add it to multiple layers.

```
    CABasicAnimation* fadeIn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeIn.duration = 0.35;
    fadeIn.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0];
    fadeIn.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.indicatorBars.count; i++) {
        [self.indicatorBars[i] addAnimation:fadeIn forKey:@"opacity"];
    }
```

Comment: But what if I want to have a different set of animations applied to different layers...simultaneously?

For example:


`NSArray* animations1 = ....
NSArray* animations2 = ....

CAGroupAnimation* anim1 = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
anim1.animations = animations1;
[layer1 addAnimation:anim1];
[layer2 addAnimation:anim2];`

Apologies in advance if I'm just thinking about this wrong!

Comment: It seems to not be animating. My guess was that it was because I added the animation to the layer outside the context of an animation block. Tried doing it with `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` but that didn't seem to do it either. Perhaps the issue is I need to find a better way to debug Core Animation objects (like how can I inspect that values are actually changing over time? Separate question, but just not sure the best way to go about diagnosing this).

Comment: Are you able to post the actual code? It could be a matter of the values you're using. It's definitely not because you're trying to do multiple animations, and Core Animation doesn't require or use UIView animation blocks.

Comment: Yes, code snippet posted above. I've also tried it without the CAMediaTime() preceding my time offsets. It didn't work in either case so I'm still not sure the correct usage.

Comment: Could be your key paths. Double check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html

- Also maybe don't set your key to nil for the animation?